# How can I use sequelize where others model?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

```
const {
    group,
} = req.query
const where = {}

if (group) where['$Group.title$'] = group

models.User
    .findAll({
      where,
      attributes: getAttributes({model: 'User'}),
      include: [{
        model: models.Group,
        attributes: ['title']
      }, {
        model: models.PointHistory
      }]
    })
    .then(result => {
      res.json(result)
    })
    .catch(err => next(err))
```

This is my code. `$Group.title$` is not working.
I want to add search option by Group name. But this is another model.
How can I fix it?

Comment: "... is not working" is not description of the problem. Please include details, including expected behavior and error messages (if any)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
models.User
    .findAll({
      where,
      attributes: getAttributes({model: 'User'}),
      include: [{
        model: models.Group,
        attributes: ['title'],
        where: {
          title: {
            $like: //yourSeachString
          }
        }
      }, {
        model: models.PointHistory
      }]
    })
    .then(result => {
      res.json(result)
    })
    .catch(err => next(err))
```